# How to install evil-snipe-enable-alternate-f-and-t-behaviors on Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, variables, install

I am trying to install "evil-snipe" with evil-snipe-enable-alternate-f-and-t-behaviors on Spacemacs.

The instruction on https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bvim/evil-snipe are a bit vague.

evil-snipe-enable-alternate-f-and-t-behaviors should be set to 't'.
This is in my .spacemacs file:

```
...
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
'(
  evil-snipe
...
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
...
(setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
          '((evil-snipe :variables evil-snipe-enable-alternate-f-and-t-behaviors t)))
...
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (evil-snipe 
...
```

And restarted Spacemacs.

But evil-snipe-enable-alternate-f-and-t-behaviors is nil, when I needs to be t.
SPC h d v (describe variable) evil-snipe-enable-alternate-f-and-t-behaviors:

```
evil-snipe-enable-alternate-f-and-t-behaviors is a variable defined in ‘config.el’.
Its value is nil

Documentation:
if non nil f/F/t/T behaviors are replaced by evil-snipe behavior.
```

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you look up a few lines in your `.spacemacs`, you'll see that `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` already *is* in a `setq-default`.  So what the docs are suggesting is that you do something like this:

```
...
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
'(
  (evil-snipe
   :variables
   evil-snipe-enable-alternate-f-and-t-behaviors t)
  ...
```